# Swift function with a parameter which conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, generics, assembly, llvm

I want to write a function with a parameter which conforms to a protocol. There are 2 options:

```
// option 1:
func foo<T: CustomStringConvertible>(obj: T) {
    print(1)
    print(obj.description)
}
// option 2:
func foo(obj: CustomStringConvertible) {
    print(2)
    print(obj.description)
}
// test:
foo(Float(10.0))
```

Both of them work as expected, and the 2nd will override the 1st if they coexist.

Does the compiler generate the same binary?

Comment: "My question is which one is better?" Not a good question for Stack Overflow, as it is primarily opinion-based and answers will be based off of opinion, not fact.

Comment: @JAL The question has been fixed in this regard; surely it should be reopened now?

Comment: "which one has better performance and code footprint?" Define better.  Do you mean which code runs faster?  Which produces less assembly?  It's still unclear what you mean by better.  If you removed that and just asked "Does compiler generate same binary?" I could answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two programs:

foo1.swift

```
func foo<T: CustomStringConvertible>(obj: T) {
    print(obj.description)
}
```

foo2.swift

```
func foo(obj: CustomStringConvertible) {
    print(obj.description)
}
```

These programs will generate nearly identical assembly to start, but will differ when it reaches the function instructions.  In the first program, you're utilize the power of Swift generics.  In the second program, you're casting an object to conform to a protocol.

We can see the instructions generated from each program by using llvm:

```
swiftc -emit-assembly foo1.swift
swiftc -emit-assembly foo2.swift
```

foo1 assembly:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 10
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    _globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_token6@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    __TZvOSs7Process5_argcVSs5Int32@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    movl    %edi, (%rcx)
    cmpq    $-1, (%rax)
    movq    %rsi, -8(%rbp)
    je  LBB0_2
    movq    _globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_token6@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi
    movq    _globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_func6@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    callq   _swift_once
LBB0_2:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    __TZvOSs7Process11_unsafeArgvGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerGS0_VSs4Int8__@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, (%rcx)
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .private_extern __TF3foo3foouRq_Ss23CustomStringConvertible_Fq_T_
    .globl  __TF3foo3foouRq_Ss23CustomStringConvertible_Fq_T_
    .align  4, 0x90
__TF3foo3foouRq_Ss23CustomStringConvertible_Fq_T_:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $176, %rsp
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    movq    %rsi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rdi, -40(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    movq    %rsi, -48(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -56(%rbp)
    callq   __TTSg5P____TFSs27_allocateUninitializedArrayurFBwTGSaq__Bp_
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    __TMdSS@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 24(%rdx)
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    -8(%rcx), %rsi
    movq    -40(%rbp), %r8
    movq    %rsi, -64(%rbp)
    movq    %r8, %rsi
    movq    %rdx, -72(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, %rdx
    movq    -64(%rbp), %r9
    movq    %rax, -80(%rbp)
    callq   *40(%r9)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -56(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, -88(%rbp)
    callq   *(%rcx)
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    32(%rsi), %rdi
    movq    -88(%rbp), %r8
    movq    %rdi, -96(%rbp)
    movq    %r8, %rdi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -96(%rbp), %r9
    movq    %rax, -104(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -112(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, -120(%rbp)
    callq   *%r9
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -104(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)
    movq    -112(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 8(%rax)
    movq    -120(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rax)
    callq   __TIFSs5printFTGSaP__9separatorSS10terminatorSS_T_A0_
    movq    %rax, -128(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -136(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, -144(%rbp)
    callq   __TIFSs5printFTGSaP__9separatorSS10terminatorSS_T_A1_
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    -128(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -136(%rbp), %r8
    movq    %rdx, -152(%rbp)
    movq    %r8, %rdx
    movq    -144(%rbp), %r9
    movq    %rcx, -160(%rbp)
    movq    %r9, %rcx
    movq    %rax, %r8
    movq    -152(%rbp), %r9
    movq    -160(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rsp)
    callq   __TFSs5printFTGSaP__9separatorSS10terminatorSS_T_
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rax
    callq   *24(%rax)
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -96(%rbp), %rax
    callq   *%rax
    addq    $176, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .linker_option "-lswiftCore"
    .linker_option "-lobjc"
    .section    __DATA,__objc_imageinfo,regular,no_dead_strip
L_OBJC_IMAGE_INFO:
    .long   0
    .long   768


.subsections_via_symbols
```

foo2 assembly:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 10
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movq    _globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_token6@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    __TZvOSs7Process5_argcVSs5Int32@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    movl    %edi, (%rcx)
    cmpq    $-1, (%rax)
    movq    %rsi, -8(%rbp)
    je  LBB0_2
    movq    _globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_token6@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdi
    movq    _globalinit_33_1BDF70FFC18749BAB495A73B459ED2F0_func6@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    callq   _swift_once
LBB0_2:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    __TZvOSs7Process11_unsafeArgvGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerGS0_VSs4Int8__@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, (%rcx)
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .private_extern __TF3foo3fooFPSs23CustomStringConvertible_T_
    .globl  __TF3foo3fooFPSs23CustomStringConvertible_T_
    .align  4, 0x90
__TF3foo3fooFPSs23CustomStringConvertible_T_:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $176, %rsp
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    movq    %rdi, -40(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    callq   __TTSg5P____TFSs27_allocateUninitializedArrayurFBwTGSaq__Bp_
    movq    __TMdSS@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 24(%rdx)
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    24(%rcx), %rdi
    movq    -8(%rdi), %rsi
    movq    %rdi, -48(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %r8
    movq    %rsi, -56(%rbp)
    movq    %r8, %rsi
    movq    -56(%rbp), %r9
    movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -72(%rbp)
    callq   *16(%r9)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    32(%rcx), %rdx
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    %rsi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rsi), %r8
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rdx, -80(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    %r8, -88(%rbp)
    callq   *40(%r8)
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, -96(%rbp)
    callq   *(%rcx)
    movq    -96(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -88(%rbp), %r8
    movq    %rax, -104(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -112(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, -120(%rbp)
    callq   *32(%r8)
    movq    -72(%rbp), %rax
    movq    -104(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)
    movq    -112(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 8(%rax)
    movq    -120(%rbp), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rax)
    callq   __TIFSs5printFTGSaP__9separatorSS10terminatorSS_T_A0_
    movq    %rax, -128(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -136(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, -144(%rbp)
    callq   __TIFSs5printFTGSaP__9separatorSS10terminatorSS_T_A1_
    movq    -64(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    -128(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -136(%rbp), %r8
    movq    %rdx, -152(%rbp)
    movq    %r8, %rdx
    movq    -144(%rbp), %r9
    movq    %rcx, -160(%rbp)
    movq    %r9, %rcx
    movq    %rax, %r8
    movq    -152(%rbp), %r9
    movq    -160(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rsp)
    callq   __TFSs5printFTGSaP__9separatorSS10terminatorSS_T_
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rdi
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rsi
    movq    -88(%rbp), %rax
    callq   *24(%rax)
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movq    24(%rax), %rcx
    movq    -8(%rcx), %rdx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
    callq   *(%rdx)
    addq    $176, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .linker_option "-lswiftCore"
    .linker_option "-lobjc"
    .section    __DATA,__objc_imageinfo,regular,no_dead_strip
L_OBJC_IMAGE_INFO:
    .long   0
    .long   768


.subsections_via_symbols
```

The differences exist mostly in `Ltmp5`, where the protocol conformance requires additional instructions.

Online diff [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/mou3qesf).

If your end goal is fewer instructions and want to use generics, then foo1 is objectively "better."  If you just want to check for protocol conformance, foo2 is objectively "better" and easier to read.